# What the meaning of valueAST in GraphQL?

Tags: graphql

In definition of GraphQLScalarTypeConfig is:

```
type GraphQLScalarTypeConfig<InternalType> = {
  name: string;
  description?: ?string;
  serialize: (value: mixed) => ?InternalType;
  parseValue?: (value: mixed) => ?InternalType;
  parseLiteral?: (valueAST: Value) => ?InternalType;
}
```

see: http://graphql.org/graphql-js/type/#graphqlscalartype

What's the meaning of `valueAST` and of the complete expression of `parseLiteral?: (valueAST: Value) => ?InternalType;`?

I know "parseLiteral?" mean parseLiteral is optional, but the rest of line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AST == Abstract Syntax Tree

All GraphQL queries are converted in a AST datastructure. AST is the base of the Graph QL internal query processing.

see https://mikewilliamson.wordpress.com/2016/09/15/graphql-and-security/

I assume "(valueAST: Value) => ?InternalType;" mean: valueAST is an interal GraphQL type.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to note about the code you showed is that after each colon follows the type of the specified field.

So the line `name: string;` means that field `name` is of type `string`.

However, in the 3 cases of `serialize`, `parseValue` and `parseLiteral` the *type* is actually a *function*! So, what you see after the colon here are the *input and return* types of that function.

The line you're asking about `parseLiteral?: (valueAST: Value) => ?InternalType;` means that we have an *optional* (as you already said) function that is called `parseLiteral` and that takes as an *input* argument an AST and *returns* a value of type `?InternalType`.

Comment: Thank you! I assume you are facebook developer. Your explanation is good! Better if facebook document this kind of syntax in ref documentation or write a document about this syntax rules and link on this document on GQL documentation. So a lot of developers can save googletime!!!